# Lexicographical comparison of integers

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I want to compare two small (<=20) sets of integers (1..20) lexicographically.

The sets are represented by single integers, e.g.
1, 2, 4, 6
will be represented as

```
 ... 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
(... 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
```

So where there's a 1 the number is present in the set.

Could someone verify if this code is correct?

```
bool less_than(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    unsigned tmp = a ^ b;
    tmp = tmp & (~tmp + 1); //first difference isolated
    return (tmp & a) && (__builtin_clz(b) < __builtin_clz(tmp));
}
```

The `__builtin_clz` part is for the case when `b` is a prefix of `a`.
The case of an empty set is handled elsewhere (`__builtin_clz` is undefined for 0).

EDIT:

```
bool less_than(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    unsigned tmp = a ^ b;
    tmp &= -tmp; //first difference isolated
    return ((tmp & a) && (__builtin_clz(b) < __builtin_clz(tmp)))
            || (__builtin_clz(a) > __builtin_clz(tmp));
}
```

and

```
bool less_than_better(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    unsigned tmp = a ^ b;
    tmp &= -tmp; //first difference isolated
    return ((tmp & a) && tmp < b) || tmp > a;
}
```

appear to be both correct.
(Tested versus a naive implementation using `std::lexicographical_compare` on tens of millions of randomized tests)

The second one is more portable though since it doesn't use `__builtin_clz`.
The difference in speed on my machine is negligible (the second one being ~2% faster), however on machines without `__builtin_clz` as one processor instruction (e.g. BSR on x86) the difference will probably be huge.

Comment: I think tests are the best way to verify if the code is correct. Or write its execution step by step on paper

Comment: A set is usually unordered - when is one set less than another? Would `1000` (4) be less than `0110` (5)? Your method would return `tmp=1000^0110=1110; tmp=1110 & 0010 = 0010; return (0010 & 1000) && ( 28 < 30 );` or since `0010 & 1000 == 0`: false. It would also return false for `1100` (7) and `0011` (3): `tmp=1100^0011 = 1111; tmp &= (0000+1) -> tmp=0001;'; Then, `(tmp & a)` is `(0001 & 1100)` = 0, so false again.

Comment: @Kenney The sets are sorted in increasing order and compared **lexicographically**. I call them sets just because no element can appear twice. For the examples you provided my code behaves correctly.

Comment: You've probably tested that on an Intel cpu because on AMD `bsr` is super slow.

Comment: @harold Yes, I have an i7-4800MQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not correct in the case that `a == 0`. This should return true unless `b == 0`, but since `tmp & a` will be false regardless of the value of `tmp` (which will be the lowest-order 1-bit in b), the function will return false.

`a` should be "less than" `b` if:

```
1. `a` is a proper prefix of `b`, or
2. The lowest-order bit of `a^b` is in `a`.
```

The first condition also handles the case where `a` is the empty set and `b` is not. (This is slightly different from your formulation, which is "(The lowest-order bit of `a^b` is in `a`) and not (`b` is a proper prefix of `a`).)

A simple test of the case "`a` is a proper prefix of `b`", given the fact that we have the the lowest-order bit of `a^b` in `tmp`, is `tmp > a`. That avoids the use of `__builtin_clz` [Note 1].

Also, you could write

```
tmp = tmp & (~tmp + 1);
```

as

```
tmp &= -tmp;
```

but I think that most C compilers will find that optimization on their own. [Note 2].

Applying those optimizations, the result would be (untested):

```
bool less_than(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    unsigned tmp = a ^ b;
    tmp &= -tmp; //first difference isolated
    return tmp > a || tmp & a;
}
```

---

#### Notes

1. This is worth doing because (1) even though `__builtin_clz` is builtin, it is not necessarily super-fast; and (2) it may not be present if you're compiling with a compiler other than gcc or clang.
2. `-tmp` is guaranteed to be the 2s-complement negative of `tmp` if `tmp` is an unsigned type, even if the underlying implementation is not 2s-complement. See §6.2.6.2/1 (the range of an unsigned type is 0..2<sup>N</sup>-1 for some integer N) and &6.3.1.3/2 (a negative value is converted to an unsigned integer type by repeatedly adding 2<sup>N</sup> until the value is in range.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a listing calculating all combinations for 2-bit inputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

bool less_than(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    unsigned tmp = a ^ b;
    tmp = tmp & (~tmp + 1); //first difference isolated
    return (tmp & a) && (__builtin_clz(b) < __builtin_clz(tmp));
}

#define BITPATTERN "%d%d%d"
#define BYTETOBITS(byte)  \
  (byte & 0x04 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x02 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x01 ? 1 : 0) 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  for ( int a = 0; a < 4; a ++ )
    for ( int b = 0; b < 4; b ++)
      printf("a: "BITPATTERN" b: "BITPATTERN": %d\n",
        BYTETOBITS(a), BYTETOBITS(b), less_than(a,b)
      );
}
```

And here's the output:

```
a: 000 b: 000: 0
a: 000 b: 001: 0
a: 000 b: 010: 0
a: 000 b: 011: 0
a: 001 b: 000: 0
a: 001 b: 001: 0
a: 001 b: 010: 1
a: 001 b: 011: 0
a: 010 b: 000: 0
a: 010 b: 001: 0
a: 010 b: 010: 0
a: 010 b: 011: 0
a: 011 b: 000: 0
a: 011 b: 001: 0
a: 011 b: 010: 1
a: 011 b: 011: 0
```

It doesn't seem to look correct..